# I can't make calls from ajax to my backend in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, cors

I have my backend done in `spring boot 3.1` with `spring security 6.1`

I have configured the login using `spring security` and then various controllers. When i make calls to my backend from Postman, I don't have any problem, but when I make them through `ajax`, I get the cors error in the browser console. I've tried to make the configuration of `CORS` and it didn't work for me, nor did putting the default of `spring` either. Any ideas? I put images of my classes in case they could be helpful.

> Class CorsConfig

```
package com.pms.pmsBack.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .maxAge(3600);
    }
}
```

> Class SpringSecurityConfig

```
@Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
         http
                 .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                 .sessionManagement(management -> management.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                 .addFilter(new JwtAuthenticationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()))
                 .addFilter(new JwtValidationFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()))
                 .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeHttpRequests) -> authorizeHttpRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login")
                         .permitAll()
                         .anyRequest()
                         .authenticated()
                 );

         return http.build();
    }
```

The CORS error:
[image]

[image]
If this is not enough, I will be attentive to the answers to add more information. Thank you so much

Axios example :

```
const respuesta = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/login', data)
                .then(function(response) {
                  if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                  }
                  throw new Error('Error in Request');
                })
                .then(function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
```

Comment: Always copy-paste code snippets as formatted text. It helps to copy-paste code and test. Images don't help much.

Comment: You should also copy-paste all the request/response headers & error details that you get in the dev tools network for the AJAX call that's rejected.

Comment: I have edited the question with the pasted code and an image of the error, sorry

Comment: Hmm..  So, despite the configuration, it seems it is not effective.  The error still says it did not find the ```Access-Control-Allow-Origin``` header.

Comment: In your CorsConfig, can you try adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation?

Comment: I tried this and it works, but I still get the error, although in the header response it returns the login token, which is correct. Attached image.

Comment: That error must be something else, at least the API works, JWT token is returned, and it is a 200 OK response.  The error must be related to something else.  Adding it as an answer.

Comment: But the response body is not returned by the backend, only the header

Comment: I believe, 200 OK and the JWT token themselves are sufficient. Not sure what is missing to add response too.  If you want to redirect to some other page, you may try adding `.formLogin(form -> form.defaultSuccessUrl(URL)....)` in your `HttpSecurity http` object's configuration to redirect to success page upon success. Add `failureUrl(URL)` to redirect to failure. But since you are using AJAX, you can just do whatever you want to do upon success callback.

Comment: Con ajax aunque me devuelve error, me devuelve tambien el token, asi que eso esta bien, pero lo intento con axios dentro de una web en react, y me sigue dando error sin devolverme el token. adjunto la llamada axios que estoy intentando.

Comment: What is the exact error?  `console.log` everything. Log `response`, if `response.ok` is false, not just raise a new error 'Error in Request'. If it throws an error, what is logged by catch?  Probably `response.json()` might be resulting in an error, as there is no json string in the response to parse. And what response are you expecting? What have you done in your code to give that response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `CorsConfig.java`, try adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.
This annotation will actually make it process all the registry operations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

> Note: When responding to a credentialed request, the server must specify an origin in the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, instead of specifying the "*" wildcard.

If you are trying to login with basic authentication, it won't work.

**Edit**: Oh, and if it is cookie-based ajax login, it still requires explicit domain name in header even if it's not basic auth. That article is really helpful, check it out.